# Automate and import from an attachement from Outlook to Sql Server or MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to think of a way I can make my life a bit easier this year :-)

I receive an email with an CSV attachment from one of my clients everyday, now I will save these files to a folder, add the date to the last column in the csv file, and then manually import the file.

Now my question is, is there away either SQL Server 2014 can automate this or even mysql? the reason for both is I use both on a daily bases, and how would I go about doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is really broad. You can write a macro in Outlook to export the file to a folder, and use SSIS to load it into your database. Or you can write a C# application using the Outlook Interop Assembly to do all the above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb652780%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Hi @ZoffDino, I do understand that my question does sound very broad, I would like to know what would be the quickest and easiest way to do this? Thank you for your link, I will investigate.